# (Javascript) why the catch doesn't catch the rejection?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Below is the promise chaining code:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('first');
  resolve('yes');
}).then(
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('second');
    reject('no');
  })
).catch(rej => console.log(rej));
```

And the output is :

'first'

'second'

I expected to get a 'no' output, but there wasn't.
I don't know why the catch didn't catch the rejection from the second .then()?

Answer (score 4):

`.then` only accepts a *function* as a parameter - your

```
then(new Promise
```

is passing the second `.then` a *Promise* (that gets initialized *when the `Promise` chain is created, not when the prior `Promise` resolves). But `.then` doesn't know what to do when it's passed a `Promise`, it only deals with *function* parameters.

Instead, pass `.then` a function, and have that function create the Promise to be returned, and it will be properly caught:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('first');
  resolve('yes');
}).then(
  () => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
//^^^^^^
    console.log('second');
    reject('no');
  })
).catch(rej => console.log('catch: ' + rej));
```

Comment: Just wondering, what will be the final status of the promise returned. Tried the above in the browser console and gives the final status as resolved in chrome and pending in firefox.

Comment: A `Promise` chain whose final item is a `catch` that does not throw an error will always result in a *resolved* `Promise`. (you can see this by opening your browser console - if the `Promise` chain resulted in a rejected `Promise`, you'd see something like `Uncaught (in promise) <err>`. Can only see it in browser console, not in stack snippet console)

Comment: Why is it status different for 2 browsers? Strange isn't it?

Comment: That's due to console weirdness, seems like Firefox's prints the value *immediately*, while Chrome's prints the value (or updates the value) after the `.then` and the `.catch` have had time to run

Comment: Ohh Cool! Storing the promise in a variable returns the status as fulfilled ! You were right about the console wierdness.